# DataTable serverside processing , processing stuck when returned data = null

Tags: datatables

I;m getting following error when my search query returns null.

```
Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

here is my datatable js

```
 var thisTable = $('#tb').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: '/user.js',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function ( d ) {
                d.r1 = $('#custom1').val();
                d.r2 = $('#custom2').val();
                // etc
            }
            },
```

As I know in clientside datatable if no data it show a message . how can I show that no data found message in serverside processing too?

Comment: where do you access the length property? Please show the code

Comment: @fafl : data=null given for data set since no matching data. im accessing it form json url user.js

Comment: Try to write this condition into your data function at the top to handle no data being returned: `if (d === null) {console.log("no data!"); return;}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Datatables doesnt render null values.
Use defaultContent.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [{
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "default content",
      "targets": ['_all']
  }]
} );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent

Answer (score 0):

data souldnt be null value , check in `url: '/user.js'` file and return empty string like `data=""` if data is null.
for php

```
$output = array(
            'draw' => 1,
            "recordsTotal" => 10,
            "recordsFiltered" => 10,
            'data' => array()
        );

//some functions to get data called $aaData

$output['data'] = $aaData ?: "";
```

datatable behavior will be how it should be.